# Mediawiki CSS on log out

Tags: css, mediawiki

I am new to Mediawiki.

I am not installing it in a server, I only need to run some pages that show CSS content to other people without a wiki account, for example: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/User:Xtech2020/Nested_Lists

The problem is: when I log out, CSS stops working, i tried to edit Custom CSS in Global Preferences without results.

I have researched the issue and cannot find a solution, please help.

Comment: Custom CSS is shown only to the user it belongs to. You need to edit wiki-wide CSS to make it awailable to everyone.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.

Where can I locate wiki-wide CSS?

Since I am using Mediawiki fully online, I do not have a set of folders with these dependencies but apply the styles via Preferences.

Comment: I tried typing .../wiki-wide.css in the address bar and I got this answer:
"There is currently no text in this page. You can search for this page title in other pages, or search the related logs, but you do not have permission to create this page."

Comment: Similar result editing MediaWiki:Common.css:
"You do not have permission to edit this page..."

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. If you want to edit wiki-wide JavaScript or CSS, you have to have permissions.